# can i use hadoop cloudera without root access?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

a bit of a binary question (okay, not excatly) - but was wondering if one is able to configure cloudera / hadoop to run at the nodes without root shell access to the node computers (although i can setup ssh passwordless login)?

appears from their instructions that root access is needed, at yet i found a hadoop wiki which suggest root access might not be needed ? http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, yes.  You'll just have to install from source instead of RPM or DEB.  Visit http://archive.cloudera.com/docs/ and click on one of the "Tarball" releases (either CDH2 or CDH3) in the top-right corner.

Once you get the tarball, you'll have to create a hadoop user, set some environment variables, etc.

I encourage you to ask Cloudera questions in Get Satisfaction, where we're more likely to answer your questions.

getsatisfaction.com/cloudera

Thanks, and good luck.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i'm loving cloudera's awesomness :)

Comment: PS the official Cloudera support forum is now at: https://community.cloudera.com/